# Delay the autoplay of video in fullpage.js

Tags: video, fullpage.js, autoplay

i'm searching a way to delay the autoplay using fullpage.js

In the tag i'm actually using data-src ( for lazy load ) and autoplay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**HTML**

```
<video id ="video_intro" width="XXX" height="XXX" poster=".../poster.svg">
<source data-src=".../video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source data-src=".../video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**JS**

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var video = document.getElementById("video_intro");
        video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            video.play();
          }, 2000);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it yourself using the callback `afterLoad`. Then add a setTimeout or similar:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
     setTimeout(function(){
         //playing HTML5 media elements
         $(this).find('video, audio').each(function(){
            var element = $(this).get(0);

            if( element.hasAttribute('data-myautoplay') && typeof element.play === 'function' ) {
                element.play();
            }
        });
     }, 2000); //2 seconds delay
},
```

Of course, you have to stop using the fullpage.js autoplay feature, so remove the `autoplay` property from your video. Use `data-myautoplay="true"` for the previous code above to work.

Comment: I'm unable to let it work :\
Video doesn't start at all... I tryed removing data-src, removing autoplay nothing works.